# Magento admin order minimum value based on customer group

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to set a condition by which I can restrict my admin to create orders for specific customer group.

The condition is minimum order value.

If the customer group is 'wholesale' then they have to order minimum $50.

I have already set this in frontend. In cart.phtml I put up a condition by which customer cant see the "proceed to checkout" button. And also I disabled the "place order" button for a specific customer group if someone directly accesses the checkout page from the URL.

But I also have to set this up in the admin panel. Where we can manually create orders.

There I have to also set the condition so that wholesale customers have to purchase more than $50.